# How to add options to react-perfect-scrollbar in react

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

I am using [react-perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/goldenyz/react-perfect-scrollbar) and initilizing like this

```
<PerfectScrollbar
    onScrollY={container => console.log(`scrolled to: ${container.scrollTop}.`)}>
    ... SCROLLBAR CONTENT HERE ...
</PerfectScrollbar>
```

I am trying to add [options](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar#options), in particular, `suppressScrollY`. I tried

```
<PerfectScrollbar
    options={{ suppressScrollY: true }}
    ... SCROLLBAR CONTENT HERE ...
</PerfectScrollbar>
```

and it gets ignored.

What am I missing here?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would upgrade to their latest release, which is as of this writing `1.5.6`. One of the reasons is, if you look at their docs, they previously have this prop named `option` not `options`. I've tested this theory in CodeSandBox and I can  conclude that the `options` prop pertaining to `suppressScrollY` only works on `1.5.1` and up.

Another issue that I've found is their component currently has issues with re-rendering. If you, for example, have initially set `suppressScrollY` to `true` and set its state, for example, to `false`, the changes will not reflect right away. To address this, you have to unfortunately re-mount the component.

See my comments in the code below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css";
import PerfectScrollbar from "react-perfect-scrollbar";

export default function App() {
  // holds the state if scrollY should be suppressed
  const [scrollYSuppressed, setScrollYSuppressed] = useState(true);

  // holds the state for the key prop of PerfectScrollbar
  // will be incremented to force re-mounting of component
  // due to issues with reinitializing options prop
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);

  const sampleContainer = {
    maxHeight: "100px"
  };

  const sampleContent = {
    height: "200px",
    background: "black"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PerfectScrollbar
        style={sampleContainer}
        options={{ suppressScrollY: scrollYSuppressed }}
        onScrollY={(container) =>
          console.log(`scrolled to: ${container.scrollTop}.`)
        }
        key={key}
      >
        <div style={sampleContent}></div>
      </PerfectScrollbar>
      <div>scrollYSuppressed: {scrollYSuppressed.toString()}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setScrollYSuppressed(!scrollYSuppressed);
          setKey(key + 1);
        }}
      >
        Toggle Scroll Y
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Perfect Scrollbar]

Comment: I have 1.5.8 and it's not working, I will try to switch to 1.5.6 and let you know

Comment: yeah, i believe 1.5.8 is not documented as an official stable release. check their github releases section

Comment: So it worked with 1.5.6 -- Thank you very much, will accept now